# What is the different between I put return 0 or don't put on the program

Tags: c, return

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
    {
        for (int  i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            printf("%d",i);
        }
        
    }
```

I just wonder why the result of the program whether put `return 0;` on the code or not the result is still correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no difference.

According to the C standard, you can leave out `return 0;` on the `main()` function (and **only that function**) and it will still behave as if there is a `return 0;` at the end.

The exact wording in the C standard:

> […]reaching the } that terminates the main function returns a value of 0.

From n2346 §5.1.2.2.3 Program termination.